# How do I stop my Opera browser from searching from the address bar?

Tags: browser, search, opera

I'm trying to get to individual units in my home network by their Host Name and not IP Address. But every time I try, Opera searches the internet instead of just resolving the Host Name or telling me it cannot. For example, my printer is an HP unit named- shockingly enough- HPPrinter. But every time I type that into the address bar, I get a Google search for HP Printers. How can I stop this from happening?

Windows 10, Opera 73.0

Thanks for any feedback!

Comment: bookmark the hpprinter so it is preferred over search.

Answer (score 0):

Open the Opera settings and search for the entry `Use a prediction service to help complete searches URLs typed in the address bar.`

Disable this entry and the "search-as-you-type" in the address bar is disabled.

If you type in a host-name of a device available in the local network (e.g. resolved by the used router) and press return Opera will pen the device's http site instead of performing a search request. In the host-name is unknown in local and Internet the address bar content will be sent to the configured default search engine (e.g. Google) as regular web request so that you get the response as own web page.